# Functions(procedure)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have many different queries (here is an example)

```
delete from dict.dct_task_type;       
insert into dict.dct_task_type(id_task_type,nm_task_type)
SELECT * FROM dblink 
        ('db',
         $$ select id_dict, nm_dict from dict.d_dict where kd_dict_entity = 30 $$) 
          AS dct_task_type(id_task_type bigint,nm_task_type varchar);
delete from dict.dct_task_resolution;
insert into dict.dct_task_resolution (id_task_resolution,nm_task_resolution)
SELECT * FROM dblink 
        ('db',
         $$ select id_dict, nm_dict from dict.d_dict where kd_dict_entity = 32 $$) 
          AS dct_task_resolution(id_task_resolution bigint,nm_task_resolution varchar);
```

I want to do a job in time, for this I want to save the requests as procedures, how do I write them correctly?

```
DECLARE
  variable_name datatype;
BEGIN
  statements;
EXCEPTION
WHEN exception_name THEN
  statements;
END;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
```

Write an example with my values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dict.only_dict (
)
RETURNS void AS
$body$
    BEGIN
delete from dict.dct_task_type; 
insert into dict.dct_task_type(id_task_type,nm_task_type)
SELECT * FROM dblink 
        ('ccrm_pp',
         $$ select id_dict, nm_dict from dict.d_dict where kd_dict_entity = 30 $$) 
          AS dct_task_type(id_task_type bigint,nm_task_type varchar);
delete from dict.dct_task_resolution;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
PARALLEL UNSAFE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION dict.only_dict ()
  OWNER TO mb_owner;
```

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ... RETURNS void` -> `create or replace procedure` since PostgreSQL 11.`LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'` -> `LANGUAGE sql` is enough for this set of operations. `CALLED ON NULL INPUT` -> There is no input. `SECURITY INVOKER` - `security definer` could be more flexible.